Was Psalm 68:31 prophecy concerning Egypt and Ethiopia beginning to be fulfilled during Solomon's reign?
Solomon's Reign Many events transpired during Solomon's reign that resulted in the Knowledge of Jehovah God (YHWH) being spread throughout the nations. Curiosity concerning the new Temple, amassing of wealth beyond description, treaties (and tariffs), military might, etc. would peak the curiosity of rulers and diplomats all around. But Solomon's religion was of great interest because he worshipped only one God.
We read that Solomon married an Egyptian lass...so his sons by her would be part Egyptian princes! (1 Kings 3) And this "affinity" with Egypt would draw other Egyptian princes to Israel to inquire about Solomon's religion, among other things.
And also, the Queen of Sheba is famous for her visit to Israel. (1 Kings 10) [See BH.SE #97204 for a description of the large area that ancient Ethiopia covered...which most probably included Sheba.]
So could it be concluded that Psalm 68 of David was beginning to be fulfilled?

Princes shall come out of Egypt; Ethiopia shall soon stretch out her hands unto God. Sing unto God, ye kingdoms of the earth; O sing praises unto the Lord. (Psalm 68:31-32)


Short Answer: Yes, I think that can indeed be argued that Psalm 68:31 was beginning to be fulfilled during Solomon’s reign.
In fact Clarke's Commentary does present an argument for this:

Verse Psalms 68:31. Ethiopia shall soon stretch out her hands unto
God. — This verse had its literal fulfilment under Solomon, when Egypt formed an alliance with that king by his marriage with Pharaoh's daughter; and when the queen of Sheba came to Jerusalem to hear the wisdom of Solomon. But as this may be a prophetic declaration of the
spread of Christianity, it was literally fulfilled after the
resurrection of our Lord. There were Egyptians at Jerusalem on the day
of Pentecost, who, St. Hilary tells us, on their return to their own
country proclaimed what they had seen, and became in that country the
ambassadors of Christ. The Ethiopian eunuch was one of the first among
the Gentiles who received the Gospel. Thus princes or chief men came
out of Egypt, and Ethiopia stretched out her hands to God....

Dr. Constable’s Expository Notes provide another perspective on the fulfillment of Psalm 68:31 during Solomon’s reign. According to Dr. Constable:

David next called on God to manifest His strength afresh. He foresaw
that foreign kings would fear Yahweh when they heard about all the
powerful victories He had won for His people and when they saw His
magnificent temple. This in fact occurred during Solomon’s reign, as attested by the Queen of Sheba’s testimony (1 King Psalms 10:1-13).
The beasts, bulls, and calves to which David referred probably
represent foreign rulers. He saw them bringing tribute. This also
happened when Solomon reigned. David predicted that the Lord would
defuse rebellions and cause potential enemies to make peace with
Israel out of respect for her God.

That being said, Calvin’s Commentary on Psalm 68:31 provides a different perspective on the fulfillment of this prophecy. According to Calvin, the prophecy is not limited to the events during Solomon’s reign but extends to the time of Christ.
Calvin's Commentary on the Bible:

31.Princes shall come out of Egypt. He resumes the strain of thanksgiving, and confirms what he had previously asserted, that kings
would come and pay tribute unto God. The examples which he brings
forward are those of the Egyptians and Ethiopians. This sufficiently proves that the prediction must be extended to Christ, by whom the Egyptians and Ethiopians were brought under the sway of God. The word
תריף, tarits, translated, shall soon stretch out, might have been
rendered, shall cause to run. (61) But it seemed necessary to soften
the harshness of the figure. It is doubtful whether the allusion be to
the promptness with which they should yield subjection, or whether he
means that they would stretch out their hands to entreat pardon, this
being an attitude common to suppliants. According to either
interpretation, it is their submission which is intended, and it is
enough to know that David asserts that Ethiopia and Egypt would come
under the power of God, and not they only, but the most distant parts
of the world.

Gill's Exposition of the Whole Bible also takes this stance.
